# SignalR first call after event is slow

Tags: wpf, signalr

I have a WPF client hitting SignalR services.  It's a standard MVVM architecture with async button commands and async/await pattern for calling the services.

My SignalR client is a singleton in which the connection is started once when the app is initialized.

After a click event the very first call to signalr is always super slow.  It is taking like 5 seconds for a trivial noop call (like just returning true).

After that first call, then all subsequent calls return normally fast as you would expect.  And the behavior is repeated after every click virtually every time.  Sometimes it will be fast after waiting several minutes.

I've tried rearranging and commenting out calls, fiddling with the thread pattern, but always the same result.  That first call is too slow.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: Turn on logging and check what's happening there. Show some code.

Comment: I bet your singleton is just a static member of a class just used for SignalR... Apps written in .NET only actually call the class's static constructors (or static initalisers) when the class is first referenced/called - not at start up of the app...

Comment: This turned out not to be related to SignalR.  After running a profiler I discovered a prior call pulling a gig of data across the socket.  My call in question was always backed up behind it.